# Laravel Automatic Logout and sometimes Token Mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I used Laravels built in Auth. Needed to change some paths and stuff. Everything worked fine at the beginning. But I noticed I get randomly logged out. Laravel returns mit to the login-page. Also, Sometimes when I try to login there, three different things can happen and I dont know why:

1. Page reloaded, Inputs gone
2. Token Mismatch Error
3. Logged in

This is my login view:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/backend/login') }}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}

     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
         <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">@lang('admin/login.mail')</label>

         <div class="col-md-12">
             <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

             @if ($errors->has('email'))
                 <span class="help-block">
                     <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                 </span>
             @endif
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
         <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">@lang('admin/login.password')</label>

         <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
         </div>
     </div>


     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's some problem with the **Session**, on which Laravel version are you working on?

Things you need to check to make sure the Sessions are working well:

- Make sure you have the proper permissions on the /storage/* directory.
- Search for *session()->flush()* on your project, it destroys the currently session.
- Remember if you do a *dd()* or *die()* when you are storing a session, it will be not stored.
- You need to have this PHP extensions installed:

  - *Mbstring*
  - *Tokenizer*
- The session **middleware** is on the right loader order:

On *App\Http\Kernel.php*, this is the default kernel middleware order (Laravel 5.3)

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

];
```

If you can provide more information I can try to help you more, hope it helps you :)

Comment: i currently have this problem, randomly logout. and i have session flush on my function signout. is that what happens?